# how to switch from automatic dhcp to manual setting of the wireless network

Tags: network-manager, documentation, dhcp

When waking up from sleeping my netbook (ubuntu 11.04) is very fast (less than 10 secs). However most of the time building up the wlan connection takes 30 secs. Somewhere I read, that setting your wireless at home to manual setting would speed up the connection process.

Could somebody explain me what to put into the fields of gnome network manager after choosing manual?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you mean something like this...

run `nm-connection-editor` , go to tab wireless, choose network that youre connecting to and then change method from dhcp to manual, click add, type your current IP, netmask and gateway, then add your dns servers. Your can find your current ip, netmask, dns etc if you right click on network-manager applet, then connection information, or by running `grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf` for dns and `ifconfig` for rest

if you have more computers on same network, choose ip adress that isnt in your dhcp server range ( to prevent situations when dhcp server assing same  ip as yours to other computer )